# How to pre optimise image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, performance

I have a new react app where I’m rendering out a collection of images pulled from a local JSON file.

The images are hosted on an aws s3 bucket that I don’t have access to. The images are currently being rendered on the front end at an intrinsic size of 5000px+, which is obviously killing performance.

My question is, how can I pre optimise the images within react so they load in at a smaller intrinsic size?

I don’t have budget to use something like ImgIX but I can use a 3rd party react library if necessary?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize the images displayed in your React app to load at a smaller intrinsic size, you have a few options:

Image Resizing Libraries: You can use third-party libraries in your React app that provide image resizing and optimization functionality. These libraries allow you to dynamically resize and optimize images before rendering them on the front end.

react-image-resizer: This is a simple React library that allows you to resize images on the fly by specifying desired dimensions.
react-image: This library provides advanced features like lazy loading, placeholders, and automatic responsive images.

Here's an example of how you can use the react-image-resizer library:

Install the library using npm or yarn:

```
npm install react-image-resizer
```

Use the library in your React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ImageResizer from 'react-image-resizer';

const ImageComponent = () => {
const imageUrl = 'path_to_your_image'; // Replace with your image URL

  // Resize the image to desired dimensions
const resizedImageUrl = ImageResizer.resize(imageUrl, 300, 200); // Adjust 
 dimensions as needed

  return <img src={resizedImageUrl} alt="Optimized Image" />;
};

export default ImageComponent;
```

Consider implementing lazy loading for your images to further improve page loading times. You can achieve this by using the loading="lazy" attribute on your img tags. This attribute instructs the browser to load images as the user scrolls down the page, reducing the initial page load time.

```
<img src={resizedImageUrl} alt="Optimized Image" loading="lazy" />;
```

By combining image resizing and lazy loading techniques, you can optimize the performance of your React app while displaying images from your AWS S3 bucket.

Go through this documentation for more info:- `https://algobook.info/docs/image-resizer`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. This seems to be something you can use on the click of a button E.G. a photo uploader. What I'm looking to do is to take really large images that are stored in my clients S3 bucket and display compressed versions on the frontend. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that?